# What are the units for OpenTSDB's Rate function?

Tags: metrics, opentsdb, grafana

Let's say I have a byte counter metric that increments once per second. If I plot it, I will get a monotonically increasing plot. The Y-axis is labeled 'bytes'.

I want to plot the rate of change of my counter, so I click the "Rate" checkbox. Rate is change per unit time, but what is that unit? What label should the Y-axis have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rate feature is a OpenTSDB query feature. According to the [OpenTSDB docs](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/index.html)

> The rate is the first derivative of the values. It's defined as (v2 -
>   v1) / (t2 - t1).  Therefore you will get the rate of change per
>   second. Currently the rate of change between millisecond values
>   defaults to a per second calculation.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I don't know why they say 'therefore' if they haven't defined the unit of t1 and t2, but if it's seconds then it's seconds. Thanks!